# Leaf and root record in DB2

Tags: db2

I have a scenario like below.

In a table A the records are below.

```
col1   col2
----   ----
P1     P2                                  
P2     P3                        
P3     P4
```

Now I want a query to get the output as below.

```
col1   col2
----   ----
P1     P4
```

Which means P1 is linked to P2 then P2 Linked to P3 and then P3 linked to P4. So we need to get P1 to P4. Can any one suggest how to do this in DB2?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE.

```
WITH cte (level, col1, col2) AS (
 SELECT 1, col1, col2
 FROM table_a
 WHERE col1='P1'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT cte.level+1, cte.col1, a.col2
 FROM table_a a
 INNER JOIN cte ON cte.col2=a.col1
)
SELECT 
 col1, MAX(col2) as col2, max(level) as level
FROM cte
GROUP BY
 col1
;
```

This [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96309/2) is for SQL Server 2012, but the syntax is the same for DB2 from what I remember.

**EDIT:**

Also, you can turn on Hierarchical queries and use the [CONNECT BY](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052877.html) syntax.

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT col1 as col1, col2 as col2
FROM table_a
START WITH col1='P1'
CONNECT BY PRIOR col2 = col1
 )
SELECT col1, MAX(col2) as col2
FROM cte
GROUP BY col1
;
```

The following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/866d7/32) is for Oracle, but DB2 should be the same.

Comment: A recursive CTE is also a "hierarchical query".

Comment: True. Thanks for the tip. I guess I should have said "turn on CONNECT BY syntax support for hierarchical queries".

Comment: OP, if this answer worked for you please consider accepting it as the answer or let me know why it wouldn't work for you.